# Magento 2: Access Denied Error generated in report while the browser page is loading

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

> [2017-10-06 04:20:22] main.CRITICAL: exception 'PDOException' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx'
>   (using password: YES)' in
>   /home/xx-xx/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129

```
I have Changed Folder/Files permission to 755/644 respectively
```

Answer (score 0):

recommend setting the permissions as follows:

```
All directories have 770 permissions.

770 permissions give full control (that is, read/write/execute) to the owner and to the group and no permissions to anyone else.

All files have 660 permissions.

660 permissions mean the owner and the group can read and write but other users have no permissions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Database credentials and your DB user permission.